# How to backup mongodb on a meteor app deployed with MUPX

Tags: meteor

I've deployed my Meteor app with MUPX with mongodb on the server.

MUPX puts mongodb in a docker container.

How do I back it up?

I ran the command `docker exec -it mongodb mongodump`

and it looked like it did a dump. but when I type `ls` I don't see any files. I think it dumped the files inside the docker container.

How can I access the dump files on my server? And then transfer them to my local computer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to learn more about how to use docker.

So first after running the command docker exec -it mongodb mongodump

The dump was inside the docker container.

To see running docker container type

```
docker ps
```

Check out the files in the container with name mongodb by using command

```
docker exec -it mongodb ls
```

You will see the dump directory. To copy it over to outside the container, to your server use

```
docker cp mongodb:dump .
```

that will copy the dump directory into your current directory. Then just use scp to copy from to your local computer