# I am getting an empty directory after running mongodump

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, digital-ocean

I want to do a backup of my MongoDB for a Meteor app on Ubuntu 14.04 on Digitalocean. So I ran the command

`mongodump -d dbName -o ~/backups/first_backup`

The log i see is this

```
connected to: 127.0.0.1 
Tue Jun 14 09:10:58.240 DATABASE: dbName      to     /home/kenshinman/backups/first_backup/dbName
```

Then when I visit the path, I see a blank folder with the dbName. 
Am I doing something worng?

But I also found out that the `mongoexport`  command is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Thanks to [nearpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2084311/nearpoint) for his solution. Since I uploaded my MeteorJs app with Mupx, MupX placed my mongodb in a container using [Docker](https://www.docker.com/)

So, I followed his steps and It worked fine.

[Here's his solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32793352/how-to-backup-mongodb-on-a-meteor-app-deployed-with-mupx)

Comment: I am facing the problem in my local Db so could you please let me know why this is happening . It will create an empty directory via meteor name.